# Python 2 str.decode('hex') in Python 3?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, encoding, character-encoding

I want to send hex encoded data to another client via sockets in python. I managed to do everything some time ago in python 2. Now I want to port it to python 3.

Data looks like this:

```
""" 16 03 02 """
```

Then I used this function to get it into a string:

```
x.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '').decode('hex')
```

It then looks like this (which is a type str by the way):

```
'\x16\x03\x02'
```

Now I managed to find this in python 3:

```
codecs.decode('160302', 'hex')
```

but it returns another type:

```
b'\x16\x03\x02'
```

And since everything I encode is not a proper language, i cannot use utf-8 or some decoders, as there are invalid bytes in it (e.g. \x00, \xFF). Any ideas on how I can get the string solution escaped again just like in python 2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

'str'  objects in python 3 are not sequences of bytes but sequences of unicode code points.

If by "send data" you mean calling `send` then `bytes` is the right type to use.

If you really want the string (not 3 bytes but 12 unicode code points):

```
>>> import codecs
>>> s = str(codecs.decode('16ff00', 'hex'))[2:-1]
>>> s
'\\x16\\xff\\x00'
>>> print(s)
\x16\xff\x00
```

Note that you need to double backslashes in order to represent them in code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an standard solution for Python2 and Python3. No imports needed:

`hex_string = """ 16 03 02 """
some_bytes = bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)`

In python3 you can treat it like an *str* (slicing it, iterate, etc) also you can add byte-strings: `b'\x00'`, `b'text'` or `bytes('text','utf8')`

You also mentioned something about to encode "utf-8". So you can do it easily with:
`some_bytes.encode()`

As you can see you don't need to clean it. This function is very effective. If you want to return to hexadecimal string: `some_bytes.hex()` will do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = """ 16 03 02 """.encode("utf-8")
#Send things over socket
print(a.decode("utf-8"))
```

Why not encoding with UTF-8, sending with socket and decoding with UTF-8 again ?